# Vertically align text right of floated image, image sizes varied, responsive

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'd like to vertically align multiple lines of text to the right of a left-floated image.

However

- The image size (height and width) will vary and is unknown in advance
- The length of text varies also and will usually comprise multiple lines
- Solution needs to be responsive to adapt to varied screen sizes
- Solutions should not involve specific px width or height dimensions for images, divs or anything else

  - I don't want to use tables as the text will need to drop underneath the image in certain scenarios when there isn't enough room for the text beside the image

I've looked back through previous questions but nothing quite matches what I am looking for. It needs to work on any device so I can't use absolute px values for any dimension.

How should I style the following to achieve that?

```
<img src="image.jpg" >

<p>Here is the text that should go to the right of the image</p>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to vertically align it so that it's centered in regards to the height of the image? Also, do you have any CSS that you've already tried?

Comment: When you say you don't want to use tables, are you referring to HTML tables, or/and `display:table`? The CSS approach would allow you to set breakpoints with media queries, and change the display, so it obviously won't matter taking that approach. See my answer below.

Comment: I was trying to vertically align centred to the middle of the image, which Josh's solution does perfectly. I am happy with using display:table and am experimenting with required breakpoints etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will get you started: [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/dvp28/) - **look below for a better method.**

Basically, `vertical-align:middle` and `display:inline-block` are used on both the `p` and the `img` elements for centering.

**HTML**

```
<div class="element">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.element {
    background:rgb(134, 226, 255);
    margin:10px;
}
p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    width:70%;
    background:white;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

---

Here is better approach using `display:table`/`display:table-cell` Same HTML..

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2XgDW/4/) - semi-responsive... [**Other jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2XgDW/2/) - responsive `img` elements..

**CSS**

```
.element {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    background:rgb(134, 226, 255);
    margin:10px 0px;
    padding:10px;
}
p {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:white;
}
img {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

---

**Yet another update using media queries**

You could obviously use whatever breakpoints you want. I use 480px, as this is just for example purposes. Try resizing the window. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/2XgDW/3/)

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
.element {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    background:rgb(134, 226, 255);
    margin:10px 0px;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
p {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:white;
}
img {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.element {
    width:100%;
    background:rgb(134, 226, 255);
    margin:10px 0px;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
p {
    background:white;
}
img {
    width:50%;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
}
}
```

Comment: Very nice fiddle and obviously the better solution! (: Do you know how well this works cross-browser?

Comment: @hugoderhungrige Haven't bothered to testing it. I imagine it will work in all modern browsers. I don't expect support for IE7<. All that is being used is `vertical-align:middle` and `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks so much Josh, that has moved me on an enormous amount. I have some slight complications I am working through but it's mostly there now thanks to you. I'm still having problems with IE8, but am seeing if that's to do with my specific tweaks or not. Will let you know.

Comment: I don't want to sound negative, but I wonder how it works, since adding `float` (as requested) kills the centering.

Comment: @greenoldman If you look at the code/examples, you'll notice that I didn't float any of the elements.

Comment: That's my point :-). Strange thing OP accepted this solution, since `float` was part of the question. I found full solution for two part layout -- `display:flex`.